# Share content with All Groups

Tags: organic-groups

Is there a way around to get Share with All Groups option in the group audience field for a specfic group content type.With share with All Group I mean to say share content to all groups we are not even if are not member of.
I am using og module on drupal 7 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to it with some custom coding basically i alter the form add a one more option to group audience field and then on form validation I am checking if user has input that field then I am making a db query to grab all og groups on site and then assign the group ids to the group audience field,looks kinda hackish but did'n get any better solutions.